# Partitions of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $p_{2}(n)$ denote the number of partitions of the positive integer n into at most 2 parts. Prove for each $n \ge 4$ that $p_{2}(n) + p_{2}(n-3) = n$

I understand that I need to split this into odd and even cases - I would just like my reasoning validating. Any comments/feedback on my proof or notation are very welcome.

**Starting with the even numbers:**

The number of partitions of size 2 of an even number $n$ is given by $\frac{n}{2} + 1$

The number of partitions of size 2 of an even number $n-3$ is given by $\frac{n-3}{2} + 1$ Since $n-3$ is odd, we only take the integer part of $\frac{n-3}{2}$ which is $\frac{n}{2} -2$. Adding on the 1 gives $\frac{n}{2} -1$.

Now for the even case, we do $p_{2}(n) + p_{2}(n-3) = \frac{n}{2} +1 + \frac{n}{2} -1 =n$

**Odd Numbers**

The number of partitions of size 2 of an odd number $n$ is given by $\frac{n}{2} + 1$. Since $n$ is odd, we only need the integer part of $\frac{n}{2}$ which is $\frac{n-1}{2}$. So we have $\frac{n-1}{2} +1$.

The number of partitions of size 2 of an odd number $n-3$ is given by $\frac{n-3}{2} + 1$. Since $n-3$ is even, we get $\frac{n-1}{2} -1 +1 = \frac{n-1}{2}$.

Now for the odd case, we do $p_{2}(n) + p_{2}(n-3) = \frac{n-1}{2} +1 + \frac{n-1}{2}=n$

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to have a "compact view" of the arguments. From the post, the formula
$$p_2(n)=\left[\frac n2\right]+1$$
is known, and was shown. Now we can cover all cases in one breath:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_2(n)+p_2(n-3)
&=
\left[\frac n2\right]+1
+
\left[\frac {n-3}2\right]+1
\\
&=
\left[\frac n2\right]
+
\left[\frac {n-3}2+1+1\right]
\\
&=
\left[\frac n2\right]
+
\left[\frac {n+1}2\right]
\\
&=
n\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have used some properties of the floor function $[x+1]=[x]+1$ and 
$[x]
+
\left[x+\frac 12\right]=
[2x]$, where $x\in \Bbb R$, which are simpler to check in the case $x$ is half an integer.